# Laravel query string with less/greater than etc

Tags: php, rest, laravel

In laravel, I can write this in a resource controller to respond to get requests (let's say the resource is products):

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    // Handles requests such as ".../api/products?user_id=5&price=500"
    $products = Product::where($request->toArray())->get();
    return response($products);
}
```

This works fine for requests with "=", such as in the example. But what if we don't want to search for price=500, but perhaps price <= 500 or price > 500. What would be the best Laravel (and RESTful) approach for this?

Note: Laravel 5.2

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this.

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    // Handles requests such as ".../api/products?user_id=5&price=500"
    $products = Product::where('user_id', $request->user_id)->where('price', '<=', intval($request->price))->get();
    return response()->json($products);
}
```

**Or:**

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    // Handles requests such as ".../api/products?user_id=5&price=500"
    $products = Product::whereRaw("user_id=? and price<=?", [$request->user_id, $request->price])->get();
    return response()->json($products);
}
```

***Edit after @Joel Hinz comment:***

If you want also to pass the operator of the query you can add a new parameter to the url, for example

```
/api/products?user_id=5&price=500&op=1
```

Then switch the number in the controller.

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    // Handles requests such as ".../api/products?user_id=5&price=500&op=1"
    switch(intval($request->op)){
        case 1:
        $op = "<=";
        break;

        case 2:
        $op = ">";
        break;

        //and so on

        default:
        return response()->json("Wrong parameters");
        break;
    }

    $products = Product::whereRaw("user_id = ? and price $op ?", [$request->user_id, $request->price])->get();
    return response()->json($products);
}
```

Comment: I think OP wants to get the operator from the querystring as well.

Comment: Well yes, the thing is that I could of course do this, and have additional parameters such as 'maxprice' and 'minprice' etc. However, there should be a better solution, right? I mean, this is what you do all the time - request a resource and set different parameters. It seems like a lot of work to have customized parameters for max and min all the time. The beauty of $request->toArray() is that I don't even have to specify the parameters at all.